Minimum unsat core and generalization
I have a problem that has been in my head for some time, it might be already well known but i cannot find ressources on something similar :
The idea came from the will to identify the minimal unsat cores of some unsat conjonction
For this algorithms uses the way they solve the SAT problem to detect these minimal unsat cores. However if instead we had just an oracle, how would we do ?
The following present the problem in a more general way :
Definition 1.1. Let f : P(X) → {0, 1} be a function from the subsets of X
to {0, 1}. We say that f is set increasing iff A ⊆ B ⇒ f(A) ≤ f(B).
Example 1.2.
• Take f the function such that given a word return if all the letters from
some alphabet Σ are in it, where subsets could be considered as subwords.
• Take f the function such that given a set of logical propositions returns if
their conjunction is unsatisfiable.
• The f the function telling if a subset of vertex is a valid cover of a graph
Definition 1.3. Exact Oracle query problem (OQP)
Assume f : P(X) −→ {0, 1} is a set increasing function such that f(X) = 1,
f(∅) = 0, and you have access to an oracle for f. Find S ⊆ X such that
f(S) = 1 and |S| = min{|A| | A ⊆ X, f(A) = 1}.
Definition 1.4. γ-Approximate Oracle query problem (γ-OQP)
Assume f : P(X) −→ {0, 1} is a set increasing function such that f(X) = 1,
f(∅) = 0, and you have access to an oracle for f. Find S ⊆ X such that
f(S) = 1 and |S| ≤ γ min{|A| | A ⊆ X, f(A) = 1}.
Can we find any algorithms  such that for a fixed gamma > 1 , it makes a polynomial (P_γ(n) ) number of querries to the oracle solving γ-OQP for n being the size of the set $X$.
For now I used minimal vertex cover to show that there is no polynomial number of querries in the case of γ = 1, and we can get the non approximability result from this problem also.
But since it's just one problem among other that we can put in this form, I believe we should be able to show worse non approximability,
And obviously it would be interesting to see what would the best querry strategy be.
Edit :
The problem is relatively simple to understand :
You have n elements, and an increasing function f that goes from the subsets of those elements to {0,1}
You cannot read the elements in the sense that you cannot know the value element_i. The only thing you can do is select a subset of elements, and give it to an oracle of the function f
Meaning you don't know how the function f is computed, you don't even know the function f, you just have some oracle of it.
But your goal is to find a subset S such that f(S) = 1 of minimal cardinality.
This case : the exact solution and require at least an exponential number of querries to the oracle ( see this using minimal vertex cover )
This leads to the approximation problem of finding a subset S such that f(S) = 1 and S is not too big. The question is then, if we allow polynomial (in n) call to the oracle, what size of S can we achieve (compared to S_min)
For example :
Calling the oracle on all subset of size n-c require less than n^c querries. But n-c is not really great, thus the question is
Is there some constant γ such that there is an algorithm in polynomial querries return S such that $ |S| \leq \gamma |S_{min}| $. And if yes what is the value of the constant $\gamma$.

"find any algorithms - I don't understand what you want the algorithm to do.  What problem should the algorithm solve?  What are the inputs to the algorithm, and what are its output?  What are the requirements on the algorithm?  Apparently the number of queries must be polynomial.  Any other requirements?  Must its running time be polynomial, too?

It's a very general algorithm as we consider everything as a blackbox :
Input : a set of element that you cannot read, you can only consider subsets and feed them to some oracle
( If it helps you imagine those elements as encoded values that you cannot read )
the oracle represent some function f that goes from the subsets of your input to { 0,1} and you are guaranted that this function is increasing
Output : minimal subset such that the answer of the oracle on this subset is 1
Everything is a black box I don't know what you could do with time, so number of querries is enough

I don't understand what you are asking or what your comment is saying.  Please don't put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question so it is clear and contains all information needed to answer the question.  We are looking to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others in the future, in the form of high-quality questions and answers.
